# Tkinter mouse and key press at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to convert from pygame to tkinter as it seems to be much better for what I want to do, although I have hit a bit of a wall. I need to be able to call a function when both a certain key and mouse button are pressed. In pygame it was as simple as the following.

```
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if mouse[0]:
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                // function
```

I know in tkinter you can do `c.bind("<Button-1>", function)` to register mouse clicks and `c.bind("e", function)` to register key presses but I'm not sure how to get both at the same time as the button event does not pass through key presses

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is an official method to bind both `Button-1` and `Key`, but maybe you can work around it.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Label(root,text="Hi I'm a label").pack()

class Bindings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.but_1 = False
        root.bind("<Button-1>", self.mouse_clicked)
        root.bind("<e>", self.e_clicked)
        root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.mouse_release)

    def mouse_release(self,event):
        self.but_1 = False

    def mouse_clicked(self,event):
        self.but_1 = True
        print ("Mouse button 1 clicked")

    def e_clicked(self,event):
        if self.but_1:
            print ("Both keys clicked")
            self.but_1 = False
        else:
            print ("Key E pressed")

Bindings()
root.mainloop()
```